# Is the function $f(x)=1/|x|$ bounded in the interval $(-\infty,c)$, if $c<0$?

Tags: functions, upper-lower-bounds, interval-arithmetic

Is the function $f(x)=1/|x|$ bounded in the interval $(-\infty,c)$, if $c<0$? I have to show that the function $f(x)$ is bounded in the interval $(-\infty,c)$, $c<0$, by a certain constant $K$ that depends on the $c$ chosen.

Comment: You'll have hard time to prove that as $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} \vert x \vert =0$.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake when i wrote the question. Now i have fixed it

Comment: Your edit did not change the problem. The function is unbounded on any open interval with $0$ as an end point.

Comment: i wrote it wrong again

Comment: let me change it

Comment: Sorry, but even with the update of the question, it doesn't make more sense. You still have an interval that has $0$ as a bound.

Comment: And now, is it possible to bound the function by 1/abs(c)??

Comment: What is the minimum value of $\vert x \vert$ for $x \in (-\infty, c)$ with $c<0$?

Comment: you don't reach the minimum, it's just an Infimum i guess no? So the infimum it's at c

Comment: Right, it is an infimum. And what is the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is bounded. Since $x<c$ we have $|x|=-x>-c=|c|$. Hence $f(x)=1/|x|<1/|c|$ and thus the function is bounded by the constant $K=1/|c|$ on the interval $(-\infty,c)$. (and $f(x)$ is bounded from below by $f(x)\geq 0$).